# submit form in react with variable set of inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//form.js

```
const form=({seg,onSubmit,onChange})=>{
<form id="input_form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                   {seg.map(item=>
                   <>
              <input type="number" onChange={onChange} name={item} 
                type="number" required className="form-control control" id={item+1} />
                   </>
                    )}

                    
                </form>}
```

// app.js

```
state={array:[0.0,1.0], seg=3}
onSubmit=()=>{

}


 onChange=()=>{
// should update the array(as this.state.array=[0.0, inputa,inputb,inputc..., 1.0])}
```

how do i update the array? what should be the onChange, onSubmit func?
(this.state.seg is variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.setState({ seg : newValue});

Comment: You can call the setState inside onSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `seg` state property value like this

```
onChange=(event)=>{
    this.setState({seg: event.target.value});
}
```

I suppose yo need to update the array with current `seg` value.  If you want to do it using `onSubmit`, you have to use a button with type of submit. Then the button calls the `onSubmit` function. Try this.

```
<form id="input_form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    {seg.map(item =>
        <>
            <input type="number" onChange={onChange} name={item} type="number" required className="form-control control" id={item + 1} />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </>
    )}
</form>

onSubmit=()=>{
    this.setState({
        array: [...this.state.array, seg]
      })
}
```

Comment: seg is basically the no. of times <input/> is taken. I need to take all those inputs and put it between 0.0 and 1.0 in this.state.array